# How can I create multiple items with one class in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, class, methods

I have the class Furniture with:

Furniture.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Furniture {
public:
    Furniture();
    ~Furniture();
    void setname(string name);
    void setprice(double price);
    double getprice();
    string getname();
    virtual void printSpecs();
private:
    string name;
    double price;
protected:
    static int NumberOfItems;
    int Id;

};
```

furniture.cpp:

```
#include "furniture.h"

Furniture::Furniture() {
}
Furniture::~Furniture() {
}
void Furniture::setname(string name) {
    this->name = name;
}
string Furniture::getname()
{
    return this->name;
}
void Furniture::setprice(double price) {
    this->price = price;
}
double Furniture::getprice() {
    return this->price;
}
void Furniture::printSpecs() {
    cout<<"Price: "<<this->price<<endl;
    cout<<"Name: "<<this->name<<endl;
}

int main() {
    Furniture *model = new Furniture();
    model->setname("FinalDestiny");
    model->setprice(149.99);
    model->printSpecs();
    delete model;
}
```

Everything works fine but I want to add multiple furniture items with the same class and just update the NumberOfItems. Is there any way to do that?

Also, is my code ok? I mean, how can I improve it? I'm quite new to OOP and I'd like to learn some good practices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is conceptually broken. You cannot do that; you really need different objects.

Alternatively, if you really want to have multiple identical items, you can create one item and create multiple pointers to it, and maintain a *separate* count for the number of active items. A `shared_ptr` does that for instance.

That said, your code shouldn’t use pointers at all, this is a common anti-pattern in C++ code. Furthermore, your code probably shouldn’t have setters, provide a proper constructor instead:

```
int main() {
    Furniture model("FinalDestiny", 149.99);
    model.printSpecs();
}
```

Much shorter, simpler, and no possiblity of leaking memory.

Comment: @FinalDestiny It isn’t. There’s a consensus among C++ experts that getters/setters are overused in most code. They do have their uses in some codes (it’s hard to implement DAOs without them, for instance) but most code doesn’t need them. They don’t fit well with object-oriented code, where every class has one specific purpose.

Comment: Especially `getters`. No getters is good. Tell the object to do what you want. Collaborate with other objects to do the work. E.g. `printSpecs` could take a `std::ostream` object to use. This makes it easier to test as, at the moment, you are implicitly coupled to the `cout` object.

Comment: I was about to say that *setters*, in particular, are a sign that the responsibility for maintaining an object's state lies *outside* the object, which is more or less contradictory to OO principles. Between me and @PeterWood, we can now conclude that *both* getters and setters are worse than the other. It's a zen thing, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

To keep track of the number of items, you can update the number of items in the constructor:

```
Furniture::Furniture() {
   Id = NumberOfItems++;
}
```

and decrement in the destructor if you want:

```
Furniture::~Furniture() {
   NumberOfItems--;
}
```

To access the item by `Id`, you need to have an extra manager class or use a map:

```
std::map<int,Furniture*> items;
```

which you can pass as parameter to the constructor and update it there:

```
Furniture::Furniture(std::map& items) {
   Id = NumberOfItems++;
   items[Id] = this;
}
```

And, outside, you can simply retrieve items with:

```
Furniture* f = items[3];
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I show the price/name for item 1, 2, 3?  How do I set those details?

Comment: You don't. If your class represents a single piece of furniture, then you can't put many of them in it. You should have a class that contains a `std::vector<Furniture>` or something like that that will store multiple pieces of furniture.

Answer (score 2):

I would write in this way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Furniture {
public:
    Furniture(string name = "", double price = 0)
        : name(name), price(price), Id(NumberOfItems++)
    {}
    Furniture(const Furniture &f)
        : name(f.getname()), price(f.getprice()), Id(NumberOfItems++)
    {}

    void setname(string name) { this->name = name; }
    void setprice(double price) { this->price = price; }
    double getprice() const { return price; }
    string getname() const { return name; }

    virtual void printSpecs() {}

private:
    string name;
    double price;

protected:
    static int NumberOfItems;
    int Id;
};
int Furniture::NumberOfItems;

int main_furniture(int, char **)
{
    Furniture a("product 1", 100);
    Furniture x(a), y(a), z(a);
}
```

I've inlined just to simplify. What's interesting to you should be the *copy constructor* implementation, and (OT) you forget the *const* on getter...

Answer (score 0):

Just increment `NumberOfItems` in the constructor, and decrement it in the destructor.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I access the item 1, 2, 3, etc?

Comment: You want to keep a static list of the items, then, as well as a counter. Add each item to the list in the constructor, and remove it in the destructor.

Comment: @FinalDestiny The class furniture, can not act as a piece of furniture and a container of furniture at the same time. You are mixing two different concepts within single entity, Define separate container for furniture.

Answer (score 0):

Store the furniture instances in an array or better in a `vector`. You can access them with an index or iterator. The NumberOfItems field doesn't belong in the furniture class, an instance of furniture shouldn't know about how many furniture items there are in the system. Use the `size ()` method from `vector` to get the furniture item count.